# Is 2 bit per pixel image file format discontinued?

Tags: image, image-processing, bmp

I am making a simple image manipulation library, i created a .bmp image with it which is plain white with inputted dimensions. It is able to make 1, 4 and 8 bit per pixel images, but when i try to make a 2 bit per pixel image, it is not viewable through an image viewer like windows default image viewer, Photos, and an open source software, ImageGlass. I am using the Windows 11 operating system.

Are 2 bpp image files not supported anymore ?

Comment: On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_format) it says 
"The 2-bit per pixel (2bpp) format supports 4 distinct colors and stores 4 pixels per 1 byte, the left-most pixel being in the two most significant bits (Windows CE only:[21])." That seems to indicate that only Windows CE supported 2bpp.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I saw that, just wanted to be sure because i saw questions on stack asking help to convert images to 2 bpp.